# Converting to Floating Point Image from .tif

Tags: c++, tiff, iplimage

I am relatively new to C++ and coding in general and have run into a problem when attempting to convert an image to a floating point image. I am attempting to do this to eliminate round off errors with calculating the mean and standard deviation of pixel intensity for images as it starts to effect data quite substantially. My code is below.

```
Mat img = imread("Cells2.tif");

cv::namedWindow("stuff", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::imshow("stuff",img);
CvMat cvmat = img;
Mat dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&cvmat),IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
cvConvertScale(&cvmat,&dst);
cvScale(&dst,&dst,1.0/255);
cvNamedWindow("Test",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvShowImage("Test",&dst);
```

And I am running into this error

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Array should be CvMat or IplImage) in an unknown function, file ......\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 1238

I've looked everywhere and everyone was saying to convert img to CvMat which I attempted above.
When I did that as above code shows I get
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in unknown function, file ......\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp line 697

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use C++ OpenCV interface instead of C interface and use [`convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#void%20Mat%3a%3aconvertTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20int%20rtype,%20double%20alpha,%20double%20beta%29%20const) function to convert between data types.

```
Mat img = imread("Cells2.tif");  
cv::imshow("source",img);
Mat dst;  // destination image

// check if we have RGB or grayscale image
if (img.channels() == 3) {
    // convert 3-channel (RGB) 8-bit uchar image to 32 bit float
    src.convertTo(dst, CV_32FC3);   
}
else if (img.channels() == 1) {
    // convert 1-chanel (grayscale) 8-bit uchar image to 32 bit float
    img1.convertTo(dst, CV_32FC1);
}

// display output, note that to display dst image correctly 
// we have to divide each element of dst by 255 to keep 
// the pixel values in the range [0,1].
cv::imshow("output",dst/255); 
waitKey();
```

**Second part of the question** To calculate the mean of all elements in `dst`

```
cv::Salar avg_pixel;
double avg;

// note that Scalar is a vector. 
// If your image is RGB, Scalar will contain 3 values, 
// representing color values for each channel.
avg_pixel = cv::mean(dst);

if (dst.channels() == 3) {
    //if 3 channels
    avg = (avg_pixel[0] + avg_pixel[1] + avg_pixel[2]) / 3;  
}
if(dst.channels() == 1) {
    avg = avg_pixel[0];
} 
cout << "average element of m: " << avg << endl;
```

Comment: Hmm it works. However, this didn't seem to actually eliminate my round off errors. When I run the code now my average spits out a value of 1656.76 while the mean function in Matlab is returning 1776.23 and cv::Scalar z = mean(dst); is returning 1612.36... Any ideas?

Comment: You are asking a different question. The conversion approach is correct, it is probably how you calculate the mean value. Can you show your Matlab or OpenCV code for calculating the mean?

Comment: if it awnswered your question consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green

Comment: Done! Sorry never used stackoverflow before.

Comment: Thanks :)! Hmm, So I tried your edit and it's returning 1612.36 just like I had said using that cv::mean(dst); function. Do you know why the built in MATLAB function mean is returning 1776? That's quite the discrepancy.

Comment: hmm, there should't be a discrepancy. are you sure you are calculating mean on the same input image in Matlab? Is the image also converted to grayscale in Matlab?

Comment: Yes and yes. I checked and it said that it was grayscale 220448 bytes uint16 class. Those bytes are double the image size which i suspect the way MATLAB calculates the average is the cuplrit using that byte size and the classing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for calculating the average in C++ OpenCV.

```
int NumPixels = img.total();


double avg;
double c;
    for(int y = 0; y <= img.cols; y++)
        for(int x = 0; x <= dst.rows; x++)
        c+=img.at<uchar>(x,y);
        avg = c/NumPixels;

    cout << "Avg Value\n" << 255*avg;
```

For MATLAB I just load the image and take Q = mean(img(:)); which returns 1776.23
And for the return of 1612.36 I used cv:Scalar z = mean(dst);

Comment: Yes it inputs as color(although it's a really dark microscope image that looks black and white); but immediately after loading it I convert to gray using cvCvtColor(img, dst, CV_BGR2GRAY);