# Python problem with exporting numpy matrix to tiff file using cv2.imshow then reading it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tiff

I am trying to export my NumPy matrix to a `.tiff` file then to read its contents to verify if it worked. Given the following snippet

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

data = np.array([[-0.1 for _ in range(128)] for _ in range(128)], dtype=np.float32)
cv2.imwrite('temp.tiff', data)
print('tiff file written')

image = cv2.imread('temp.tiff')
print(image)
```

returns

```
tiff file written
[ WARN:0@19.816] global /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp (629) readData OpenCV TIFF: TIFFRGBAImageOK: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples
```

So then I lower down the `dtype` parameter to `dtype=np.float16`

```py
data = np.array([[-0.1 for _ in range(128)] for _ in range(128)], dtype=np.float16)
```

but then I get another error...

```
, line 50, in export_images_to_tiff
    cv2.imwrite('temp.tiff', a)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img data type = 23 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
[1]    24228 abort      python3 main.py
```

I am honestly going nuts with this feature I'm trying to implement. Is there any alternatives or fix to the above? I read the documentation but that didn't help, and looking online these error codes yield nothing relevant. Do I just assume that the tiff file was successfully written in the first 32-bit pass and call it a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cv2.imread() has a second parameter, `flags`, which specifies how to read the image file. According the the docs, the default value of the `flags` argument to `imread()` is this:

> IMREAD_COLOR
> If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image.

Source: [imread docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56), [IMREAD_COLOR docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80af660544735200cbe942eea09232eb822).

By default, OpenCV attempts to coerce a file into 3-channel color. Since you have only a single channel, that's not going to work. However, there is a flag which will work:

```
image = cv2.imread('temp.tiff', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

(Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859570/how-to-read-a-tif-floating-point-gray-scale-image-in-opencv/56876371#56876371) for pointing me in the right direction.)

Answer (score 1):

@Nick ODell's answer works but alternatively one could simply use

```py
import tifffile as tiff

tiff.imsave('temp.tiff', data)
image = tiff.imread('temp.tiff')
```

while also worked in my case.